# Separate keyvalue pairs in a map in android

Tags: android, hashmap

I have a  `Map<String, List<String>>`  as follows

```
{Accept-Ranges=[bytes], 
Connection=[Keep-Alive], 
Content-Length=[4478161], 
Content-Type=[audio/mpeg], 
Date=[Fri, 03 Aug 2012 10:04:48 GMT], 
ETag=["de2a5-4454d1-4c6186c77fb4d"], 
Keep-Alive=[timeout=15, max=100], 
Last-Modified=[Tue, 31 Jul 2012 04:15:08 GMT], 
Server=[Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu)]}
```

I want to separate the key value pairs from this and also want to get the content corresponding to each key. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/WorkingwithKeyValuePairsinaHashtable.htm) may help you

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you just want to iterate over the entries in the `Map` and then access the `key` and the `value`?

Comment: I have a key in that map and I want to get the corresponding value of that key.what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a value to a specific key by calling the `get()` method of the `Map`.

Example:

```
Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put("foobar", 1);
System.out.println(hm.get("foobar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map.entrySet() to get a set of the map entries (i.e Key, Value). Then iterate over this set and get each individual key and entry from the Entry objects that make up the set.

Comment: Sorry..The problem is that I don't know how to get each individual key and entry.Can you send me some code for that.Thanx